# Combine Substring & replace in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

I am extracting the first part of column in SQL Server using `substring` to get an order number, however some of the data has a comma after it which I would also like to remove.

This is what I'm using to extract the order number:

```
SUBSTRING([Column], 1, CHARINDEX(' ', [Column])) AS OrderNbr
```

A couple of the values are being extracted as '01234,' or '02348,'

Is there a way I can remove the comma from the data. I tried using replace but wasn't able to combine it with `SUBSTRING`:

```
REPLACE([Column], ',', ' ') AS test
```

Comment: Show us some sample data, and also the expected result. I.e. a [mcve].

Comment: Why isn't the order number simply stored as its own column?

Comment: Replace [column] inside the replace call with that long substring thing? that being said, what others said

Comment: "A couple of the values are being extracted as '01234,' or '02348,'" - show value examples of data, show expected result for each of those; include all use cases please

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you actually can combine substring and replace like this :

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE(SUBSTRING([Column], 1, CHARINDEX(' ', [Column])), ',', '') AS OrderNbr
FROM 
    YourTableName;
```

Comment: That worked a treat, thanks!

Comment: There are couple of occasions where ordernbr is not at the start of the field, how would i extract this if it is the middle of the data for this column?