# Extract string from column SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to extract an `OrderID` from a text column in SQL Server. The order number does not always appear in the same place in the column.

Example data shown here:

```
Bill Jones ORD001234 code 0839 Swindon
ORD01235 - James Brown Code 3838 Norwich
ORD01236, - Jill Scott Code 9838 Glasgow
ORD0123 - Alan Ball - Bath - Code 0879
```

The `ORD00000` value is what I need to extract from the column. However the `Order` value can be 7-9 digits in length

This is what I originally tried;

```
substring ([column], 1, CHARINDEX(' ', [column])) AS OrderNbr
```

Also gave this a go but the length of the order number did not help. I'm thinking some kind of case statement might work?

```
,substring([Notes], patindex('%ORD%', [Notes]), 8)
```

Comment: Honestly, you're likely better off doing this in a language that has strong text processing (regex) functionality; T-SQL isn't such a language.

Comment: Someone asked a similar question just a few hours ago, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77237347/combine-substring-replace-in-sql-server

Comment: That was my question but i discovered the order nbr length and placement can vary so i am looking at another solution

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One has to wonder why the order number is just dumped
into a string with other information and not stored
in its own column, or at least why the format isn't
standardized.

Part of the problem is that looking for `'%ORD%'` must
ignore a name like Frank B***ord***en. The solution must
also be able to survive a value *without* `ORD` at all or with leading garbage right *before* `ORD`.

Here's one way to do that:

```
;WITH FirstPass AS 
(
  SELECT Notes, 
         pos = PATINDEX('%ORD[0-9][0-9]%', Notes),
         rt = SUBSTRING(Notes, COALESCE(NULLIF(
              PATINDEX('%ORD[0-9][0-9]%', Notes), 0),1), 4000)
  FROM dbo.TableName
)
SELECT Notes, OrderNumber = LEFT(rt, 
           2 + COALESCE(NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', 
           SUBSTRING(rt, 4, 4000)),0),4000))
  FROM FirstPass
  WHERE pos > 0;
```

And now you know why we tend to follow patterns where each piece of data (like an order number) is stored independently, in its own column: no ugly parsing required. :-)

- [Example db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FjYIhc11)

Comment: That worked a a treat, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:`select substring(substring([Notes], patindex('%ORD%', [Notes]), 10),1,patindex('% %',substring([Notes], patindex('%ORD%', [Notes]), 10))-1)`
it first grabs the orderId with extra then clips everything after the space (including the space)

Comment: This gives the following error; Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: then your data is different from what you showed, because that code works with each of the lines you showed in your example data

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution that is using tokenization instead of parsing.

Notable points:

- `CROSS APPLY` is tokenizing *tokens* column as XML.
- XQuery `.value()` method is retrieving order token, aka order_number.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens VARCHAR(1024));
INSERT @tbl (tokens) VALUES
('Bill Jones ORD001234 code 0839 Swindon'),
('ORD01235 - James Brown Code 3838 Norwich'),
('ORD01236, - Jill Scott Code 9838 Glasgow'),
('ORD0123 - Alan Ball - Bath - Code 0879');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = SPACE(1);

SELECT t.* 
    , c.value('(/root/r[contains(text()[1],"ORD")]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS order_number 
FROM @tbl AS t
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
        REPLACE(REPLACE(tokens,',',''), @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
        ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c);
```

**Output**

| ID | tokens | order_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bill Jones ORD001234 code 0839 Swindon | ORD001234 |
| 2 | ORD01235 - James Brown Code 3838 Norwich | ORD01235 |
| 3 | ORD01236, - Jill Scott Code 9838 Glasgow | ORD01236 |
| 4 | ORD0123 - Alan Ball - Bath - Code 0879 | ORD0123 |